# Can a one-way accumulator be used in place of a digital signature?

Tags: signature, accumulators

Could a one-way accumulator be used in a manner to replace a digital signature? Can it provide a way to:

1. verify that the data has not been tampered with, and
2. verify that the message is in fact sent/signed by the one who claims to have?

[This paper](http://www.cs.stevens.edu/~mdemare/pubs/owa.pdf) discusses it, but can it safely and effectively replace DS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach of one-way accumulators aren't a satisfying alternative to DS algorithms. Basically its just another way of using hash functions to generate a Message authentication code by hashing a message and a shared secret, while the author replaces the shared secret with the identities of all participants.

While MACs are a commonly used approach of detect data manipulation, since an attacker can't forge a MAc without knowing the secret key (of course there a several attacks on different MAC schemes and several ways of finding collisions, but an overview of *collision resistance, preimage resistance resistance and second preimage resistcance* would go beyond the scope of the discussion), nobody can prove the senders identity of a received message.
Because all participants share the same key, everybody could have computed the MAC.

Digital signatures use key pairs of $(k_{pub},k_{priv})$ for every party in the protocol, so you can be sure the messages origin way Alice, if the message is signed with Alices $k_{priv}$. The most basic attack on schoolbook DS are replay attacks: An attacker Eve just need to record the message of Alice and replay it later. To prevent this (and other attacks), a challenge-response-protocol is the best way to prove your identity to somebody.

To refer to one-way accumulators, you can say:

- You **can** verify to be in possession of these data, all participants computed their identity against. But this is just a  combination of a shared secret (participants list) and your own identity.  I'm not even sure, if you can call it a MAC at all.
- You **can not** verify other messages data. ($\neq$ message integrity)
- You **can not** prove your identity, since the scheme is vulnerable to replay attacks. ($\neq$ nonrepudiability)
- You **can not** verify the identity of a messages originator.($\neq$ origin integrity)

Since the design relies on a shared message (the participants list), you also have to perform all computations again, if a member is removed or added, which would having a devastating impact for the usage of this scheme.